# Laravel Livewire Calculate Trade Analytics

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm working on a project where I need to calculate user trading analytics and update it on the user dashboard. Everything went smooth until the number of each user trades grew in number (total of 10.000 trades and above) which increase the load time. Is there a way to speed up the process?

My current code:

AnalyticsIndex.php

```
public function updateChart()
{
    $trades = $this->filterTrades();

    $tradeAnalyticsService = app(TradeAnalyticsService::class, ['trades' => $trades, 'balance' => $this->portfolio->balance]);
    $this->netProfitData = $tradeAnalyticsService->getRangeNetProfit();
    $this->winLoseData = $tradeAnalyticsService->getWinLossPercentage();
    $this->bestTradeReturn = $tradeAnalyticsService->getBestTradeReturn();
    $this->worstTradeReturn = $tradeAnalyticsService->getWorstTradeReturn();
    $this->essentialsData = $tradeAnalyticsService->getEssentialsData();
    $this->emit('updateData');
}

public function filterTrades()
{
    $trades = $this->portfolio->trades(['return', 'return_percentage', 'status', 'entry_date', 'id', 'instrument'])->latest('entry_date')->get();

    // $trades = Trade::select(['return', 'return_percentage', 'status', 'entry_date', 'id'])->where('portfolio_id', $this->portfolio->id)->orderBy('entry_date')->get();

    switch ($this->filter) {
        case '7D':
            return $trades->where('entry_date', '<=', now()->endOfWeek())->where('entry_date', '>=', now()->startOfWeek());
            break;

        case '1M':
            return $trades->where('entry_date', '<=', now()->endOfMonth())->where('entry_date', '>=', now()->startOfMonth());
            break;

        case '3M':
            return $trades->where('entry_date', '<=', now()->endOfMonth())->where('entry_date', '>=', now()->startOfMonth()->subMonths(2));
            break;

        case '6M':
            return $trades->where('entry_date', '<=', now()->endOfMonth())->where('entry_date', '>=', now()->startOfMonth()->subMonth(5));
            break;

        case '1Y':
            return $trades->where('entry_date', '<=', now()->endOfYear())->where('entry_date', '>=', now()->startOfYear());
            break;

        case '2Y':
            return $trades->where('entry_date', '<=', now()->endOfYear())->where('entry_date', '>=', now()->startOfYear()->subYears(1));
            break;

        case '3Y':
            return $trades->where('entry_date', '<=', now()->endOfYear())->where('entry_date', '>=', now()->startOfYear()->subYears(2));
            break;

        case 'All':
            return $trades;
            break;

        default:
            return $trades;
            break;
    }
}
```

TradeAnalyticsService.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\Portfolio;
use stdClass;

class TradeAnalyticsService
{
    private $trades;
    private $balance = 0;

    public function __construct($trades, int $balance)
    {
        $this->trades = $trades;
        $this->balance = $balance;
    }

    public function getNetProfit()
    {
        return $this->netProfit($this->trades);
    }

    public function getProfitFactor()
    {
        $win = $this->filterTrade('win')->sum('return');
        $lose = abs($this->filterTrade('lose')->sum('return'));

        if ($win < 1 || $lose < 1) {
            return 0;
        }

        return $win / $lose;
    }

    public function getPercentProfitable()
    {
        $winCount = $this->filterTrade('win')->count();
        $winLoseCount = $this->trades->whereIn('status', ['win', 'lose'])->count();

        if ($winCount < 1 || $winLoseCount < 1) {
            return 0;
        }

        return $winCount / $winLoseCount * 100;
    }

    public function getAverageTradeNetProfit()
    {
        $winLoseCount = $this->trades->whereIn('status', ['win', 'lose'])->count();

        if ($winLoseCount < 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        return $this->getNetProfit() / $winLoseCount;
    }

    public function getAverageWinner()
    {
        $sum = $this->filterTrade('win')->sum('return');
        $count = $this->filterTrade('win')->count();
        // dd($sum, $count);
        if ($count < 1) {
            return 0;
        }
        return $sum / $count;
    }

    public function getAverageLoser()
    {
        $sum = $this->filterTrade('lose')->sum('return');
        $count = $this->filterTrade('lose')->count();
        // dd($sum, $count);
        if ($count == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return $sum / $count;
    }

    public function getBestTradeReturn()
    {
        return $this->trades->sortByDesc('return')->first();
    }

    public function getWorstTradeReturn()
    {
        return $this->trades->sortBy('return')->first();
    }

    public function getWinCount()
    {
        return $this->filterTrade('win')->count();
    }

    public function getLoseCount()
    {
        return $this->filterTrade('lose')->count();
    }

    public function getTradeCount()
    {
        return $this->trades->count();
    }

    public function getBalanceGrowth()
    {
        return $this->balanceGrowth($this->trades);
    }

    public function getBalanceGrowthPercentage()
    {
        return $this->balanceGrowthPercentage($this->balanceGrowth($this->trades));
    }

    public function getEssentialsData()
    {
        return [
            'profit_factor' => $this->getProfitFactor(),
            'percent_profitable' => $this->getPercentProfitable(),
            'average_trade_net_profit' => $this->getAverageTradeNetProfit(),
            'trade_count' => $this->getTradeCount(),
            'net_profit' => $this->getNetProfit(),
            'longest_win_streaks' => $this->getLongestWinStreaks(),
            'longest_lose_streaks' => $this->getLongestLoseStreaks(),
            'average_winner' => $this->getAverageWinner(),
            'average_loser' => $this->getAverageLoser(),
        ];
    }

    public function getWinLossPercentage()
    {
        $winCount = $this->filterTrade('win')->count();
        $loseCount = $this->filterTrade('lose')->count();
        if ($winCount + $loseCount == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        $win = $winCount / ($winCount + $loseCount) * 100;

        $data = [
            [
                'x' => 'Win',
                'y' => $win
            ],
            [
                'x' => 'Lose',
                'y' => 100 - $win
            ]
        ];
        $data = [$win, 100 - $win];

        return $data;
    }

    public function getRangeNetProfit()
    {
        $data = array();
        $trades = $this->trades->whereIn('status', ['win', 'lose']);
        $rawDatas = $trades->groupBy(function ($item) {
            return format_string_date($item->entry_date, 'd/m/y');
        });;

        if ($rawDatas->count() > 30) {
            $rawDatas = $trades->groupBy(function ($item) {
                return format_string_date($item->entry_date, 'm/y');
            });;
        }

        foreach ($rawDatas as $key => $rawData) {
            $tempData = [
                'x' => $key,
                'y' => $this->netProfit($rawData)
            ];
            array_push($data, $tempData);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function getLongestWinStreaks()
    {
        $currentStreak = 0;
        $longestStreak = 0;

        foreach ($this->trades->whereIn('status', ['win', 'lose']) as $trade) {
            if (!($trade->status == "win")) {
                $currentStreak = 0;
                continue;
            }
            $currentStreak++;
            if ($currentStreak > $longestStreak) {
                $longestStreak = $currentStreak;
            }
        }
        return $longestStreak;
    }

    public function getLongestLoseStreaks()
    {
        $currentStreak = 0;
        $longestStreak = 0;

        foreach ($this->trades->whereIn('status', ['win', 'lose']) as $trade) {
            if (!($trade->status == "lose")) {
                $currentStreak = 0;
                continue;
            }
            $currentStreak++;
            if ($currentStreak > $longestStreak) {
                $longestStreak = $currentStreak;
            }
        }

        return $longestStreak;
    }

    private function balanceGrowth($trades)
    {
        return $this->balance + $trades->sum('return');
    }

    private function balanceGrowthPercentage($balance)
    {
        $initial = $this->balance;
        if ($initial <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($balance - $initial)  / $initial * 100;
    }

    private function netProfit($trades)
    {
        return $trades->whereIn('status', ['win', 'lose'])->sum('return');
    }

    private function filterTrade(string $status)
    {
        return $this->trades->where('status', $status);
    }
}
```

Note: The data is calculated once with wire:init and every time the user clicks on the filter button (7D, 1M, 3M, etc)

Comment: I think you are performing lots of operation on php side i think. Based on understanding you are passing all of the trade that belongs to user inside ```TradeAnalyticsService``` it seems.

Comment: Yup thats right @ManojKiranAppathurai

Comment: so instead of getting all the reocrds from DB perform the Aggregate functions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html in mysql side